# Computing the content of a ball of p-dimension

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B_p(r) = \{x \in \mathbb R^p : ||x|| \leq r\}$ be the ball with radius $r > 0$
in $\mathbb R^p$.

I wish to show that

$w_p(r) = r^pw_p(1)$

where $w_p(r)$ denote the content of $B_p(r)$.

For 2-dimension, I can easily see that $\pi r^2 = r^2\pi$

but I am not sure how I can generalize this to $p$-dimension. I was instructed to

use change of variables but is it really useful in proving this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Yes, change of variables is exactly the way to go: Scaling $x\mapsto rx$ sends the unit ball $B_p(1)$ to $B_p(r)$.

Comment: In general if you scale a dimension by $r$ th content scales by $r$ too. It follows from the equivalent relationship between a rectangle and an edge.

Comment: For those who might be interested, I gave a lot of literature references (textbook and expository paper) relating to the volume of an $n$-sphere in [this 22 June 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/F1_GTvZBEE8/m/7su4_yMrbQAJ). And yes, the Greg Egan who also participated in that sci.math thread is [the well known science fiction author with that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Egan).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way. If I am correct then by means of *content of a ball* you mean $p$-dimensional volume of the ball $B_p(r)$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) the $p$-dimensional volume of an Euclidean ball of radius $r$ in a $p$-dimensional space is $$V_p(r)=\frac{\pi^\frac{p}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{p}{2}+1)}r^p.$$ And $V_p(1)=\frac{\pi^\frac{p}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{p}{2}+1)}$, so $V_p(r)=V_p(1)r^p$.

If I am wrong, let me know and please give the definition of *content of a ball*.